# On page re-load, loading first slide

Tags: javascript

I have created a pagination script, where on click of previous and next buttons, the slides will move from 1,2,3 .. and more. Link for the same as below.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/4xvcuz6h/7/)**

Question: When the above page gets loaded, I can see slide - 1 by default. When I click next or move to slide - 2 and refresh the page, I can see slide - 2 and not slide - 1 which opens fine when loaded first. So I want slide - 1 to open every-time I refresh the page irrespective of slides moved.

The **javaScript** snippet is as below.

```
turnpage:function(setting, thepage, autocall){
    var currentpage=setting.currentpage //current page # before change
    var totalpages=setting.contentdivs.length
    var turntopage=(/prev/i.test(thepage))? currentpage-1 : (/next/i.test(thepage))? currentpage+1 : parseInt(thepage)
    turntopage=(turntopage<1)? 1 : (turntopage>totalpages)? totalpages : turntopage //test for out of bound and adjust

    document.querySelector('.prev').style.visibility=(turntopage == 1)? "hidden" : "visible";
    document.querySelector('.next').style.visibility=(turntopage == totalpages)? "hidden" : "visible";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change you code

```
//setting.currentpage=urlselectedpage || ((this.enablepersist)? persistedpage : 1)
setting.currentpage=1;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c97tfkLy/

Comment: Wow super .. It works .. +1 and accepted the answer. Thanks a lot.